# How to eliminate the same rows with NA in all groups using the tidyverse package?

Tags: r, tidyverse, na

As an example, I have daily data, divided into 3 classes. Class B has an NA on day 3. I would like to eliminate day 3 (or days based on NA) from classes A and C, even if it is not an NA. I have tried using the `drop_na()` function, but this function only eliminates the row with NA from class B.

```
library(tidyverse)

Class <- c(rep("A",10),
           rep("B",10),
           rep("C",10))

Days <- rep(1:10,3)

Values <- c(1:12,
            NA,
            14:30)

DF <- data.frame(Class, Days, Values)

DF_NA <- DF %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  drop_na()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the grouping by 'Days'

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   group_by(Days) %>%  
   filter(!any(is.na(Values))) %>%
   ungroup
```